# Kubernetes Services on Google Cloud, cookies are not passed

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, load-balancing

I have created a cluster with 2 nodes and 3 pods in each node as shown in the attached image.

Each node is exposed via Service.

One node having the pods running the front end based on react and another node running the pods with backend service based on nodeJS

Frontend and Backend are accessible via the external IP address individually.

When the frontend application makes calls to the back end via REST APIs, cookies are not passed to the backend.

The Service is configured of type LoadBalancer

**Question**: anything to be configured at the Service definition or somewhere so that cookies are passed to the node running the backend pods?

*Note*: includecredentials flag is enabled when I make REST API calls to backend from the frontend when I fetch requests made and the same is working fine when we run in a local docker image via nginx reverse proxy

[image]

Below is the code snippet used on the frontend side to make REST API calls to nodeJS backend, after the authentication in the login page in the frontend access_token and id_token are stored in the cookie and they are expected to flow as part of the REST API call as the credentials field is enabled.

```js
export function getFileMetadata(documentId: string, attributes: string) {
  return fetch(`${baseUrl}api/documents/${documentId}`, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: { 'content-type': 'application/json' },
    credentials: 'include',
    body: JSON.stringify({
      attributes,
    }),
  })
    .then(async (response) => {
      const result = await handleResponse(response);
      return result;
    })
    .catch(handleError);
}
```

Comment: what are you using to serve your react content on your front end pods? You must have some sort of service there.

Comment: I am using the default Service of type LoadBalancer configured to expose the node running the pods for frontend ..

when i use the external ip address , we are able to reach the frontend application , what i would like to know is, when the frontend makes REST api calls to backend running on same cluster in a different node which is also exposed via service , cookies are not passed to the backend

Comment: How do you perform your API call? How do you add the cookies? Do you have code example to share?

Comment: @guillaume blaquiere : I have added the code snippet used on the frontend side used to make REST API calls to nodeJS backend .. cookies stored on the client side for the application are expected flow to backend as the credentials field is enabled

Comment: Ok, thanks. you said `Frontend and Backend are accessible via the external IP address individually.` you mean, you have 2 different IP address? Do you use domain name?

Comment: yes, we have separate IP address.
as we are still in the development mode, we are using 
"http//ipaddress_of_fronend.xip.io" as domain name for frontend and for backend i am just using the ip address like "http://ipaddress_of_backend"

frontend is accessible via "http//ipaddress_of_fronend.xip.io "
backend is accessible via "http://ipaddress_of_backend"

backend url is configured in the frontend to make REST API calls